# Heroku CI running tests twice per deploy

Tags: heroku, automated-tests, heroku-ci

Looking at my tests overview in Heroku, I see that tests run twice for every build I want to push to production. The first time runs when I've opened a PR for a branch (I've prevented pushing directly to `master`) and the second after I've successfully merged.

[image: two tests in heroku ci view]

Should this be happening and is there a way to avoid duplicate test runs and only run them on the branch I'm about to merge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is expected. Whenever you merge the PR, the `master` branch is updated. So the tests are rerun there.

Let's imagine 2 PRs:

```
master
 |- commit A - PR1
 |- commit B - PR2
```

You start by merging PR1. Commit A gets added to master. Then, you merge PR2.
But when that second PR was tested, it didn't have commit A in it's tree. So your tests could be failing.